Gaussian variable estimation with asymmetric loss
Is it possible to get an explicit expression for $a$ in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ such that this is satisfied?
$$100 \cdot\int_{-\infty}^a(a-x)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx = \int_{a}^{+\infty}(x-a)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx$$
I arrived at this expression, where $a$ minimizes the expected squared difference to a Gaussian variable, where the loss is weighted more strongly for overestimation, but I don't know where to go from here.
